# golang update set time now with squirrel

Tags: mysql, go

Right now my container's timezone is different with MySQL's, and I need to run a query to just update the time field on MySQL to its timezone.
Normally, I can run the query with "edited=NOW()", but with the Golang squirrel, it does not have a proper way to set this clause.
I cannot change both my app and mysql container's timezone, and I just need to update the date in DB. 
Is there any way to do in Squirell properly?

Comment: Can you give some code for context?

Comment: Like I need to run something like this

sq.Update(tableA).
Where("id=?", tableA.ID).
Set("dt_edited", "NOW()")

But the code above does not work as it will treat the "NOW()" as string, not as a MySQL function.
And I cannot use my local time, because the app container's local time is in different timezone

I tried to run Set("dt_edited=NOW()", nil) but it does not work as well, as the squirrel will translate it into "dt_edited=NOW()=?"

Comment: You need to be more specific than "I need to run something like this".

Comment: That is the issue. All of the more complicated issues can be handled without any problem. The only thing left is to run this simple update. If other data are updated, then this dt_edited field will be auto-updated by MySQL. But the issue here is that I cannot change any other fields, but I still need to have the dt_edited field to be updated with the MySQL 's local time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of `Set(column, "NOW()")`, you need to do `Set(column, sq.Expr("NOW()"))`

Answer (score -1):

I assume you're using this [squirrel](https://github.com/Masterminds/squirrel) package, next time give a link and ideally some example code. So I assume what you really want is sql like this:

```
update tablename set dt_edited=NOW() where id=1;
```

You could easily just build that with fmt.Sprintf safely, and execute it with the db driver directly or via sq.Exec().

```
sql := fmt.Sprintf("update tablename set dt_edited=NOW() where id=%d" tableA.ID)
```

Using squirrel you probably want something like:

```
db.Exec(update tablename set dt_edited=NOW() where id=?",tableA.ID)
```

I'm not sure on the exact syntax but something like that should work fine, you just need a query object to send sql to. Don't attempt to send dt_edited=NOW() as a param as that will get escaped the id you can safely pass in that way.

---

You’re passing it as a string. Try:

```
Set("dt_edited=NOW()")
```

Comment: it will not work as the the Squirrel's SET requires 2 parameters, have to be Set("string", interface{}). I tried to pass the interface with `nil` or just nil but it did not work. It is translated into query like `dt_edited=NOW() = ?`